# How to decide the cabinet/power supply for a new pc

Tags: power-supply, compatibility, case

I'm planning to get a new pc with the following specs:

**Proc:** AMD Phenom 2 X4 945
**RAM:** 2GB or 4GB DDR3 @ 1333MHz
**HDD:** 1 TB (any one)
**Graphics Card:** Radeon 5670
**Monitor:** ViewSonic 18.5" monitor (with support for DVI+VGA)
**Motherboard:** Any entry-level Asus motherboard with a 7 series chipset

1) Does anyone know how to select a cabinet and power supply for the given configuration?

2) Do you forsee any hardware problems/incomptibilities with this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the power drain for the components you have selected. Make sure you've included **all** of them. Then decide on any future expansion you would like to do and purchase a PSU based on that.
The case you would have to purchase depends on a number of factors. The ammount of drives you want inside, the form factor of the peripherals you have selected, the PSU you will be purchasing, the cooling system you wish to have (maybe a bit extravegant that one) etc, the size of your motherboard, whether you want card readers, front USB ports etc.
 Once you have all this information you can pick which kind you need and the one you like the most out of them.

To calculate PSU Size have a look at **[This](http://extreme.outervision.com/psucalculatorlite.jsp)** or **[This](http://www.antec.outervision.com/index.jsp)** page
Cases are too subjective for someone to choose one for you. You could buy anything from **[This](http://www.google.co.uk/products/catalog?q=PC+cases&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=32780791413301413&ei=h6L2TIv4L8qmhAfs_PnhBQ&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CEkQ8wIwBA#)** to **[This](http://www.google.co.uk/products/catalog?q=PC+cases&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=7157700822184416225&ei=h6L2TIv4L8qmhAfs_PnhBQ&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CEEQ8wIwAg#)** Perhaps have a look at http://www.xcase.co.uk/ for some ideas. IMHO you will only need a Mini Tower case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Consider audible noise, you might want to avoid excessive noise impacting your productivity (or enjoyment) that you use your machine for. Visit quietpc.com (I'm a happy customer of them).

Comment: uhm.. could you do this for me please? Sorry I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Maybe if I could see an example it would be great and it would help me solve similar situations in the future. Please consider the case that I won't be adding any more components in the future. You could make any assumptions you want for any missing data. Pretty please.

Comment: @Mugen - I've updated my answer for you. I'm not doing all the leg work but it should get you there.

Comment: @Mugen, I would accept @Joe Taylor's answer if I were you. It's the best answer and should give you all you need. Be a courteous good superuser.com citizen please. Your reputation score will increase when you do this, as a by-product. Oh and by the way, +1 my comment about audible noise, that's important too. Cheers.

Comment: @Joe That definitely helped me decide on my config. I had been planning to get a 650 watts PSU but now I'll just go with a normal 400 one as my specs come to about 230 watts. Great answer Joe! @Rob "I would accept Joe..you" - I have to read it first to decide.  "be courteous ...please" Ouch! :)